# How to select xml data based on a condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath

Below is my xml

```
DECLARE @myDoc xml
DECLARE @ProdID int
SET @myDoc = 
'<Root>
<ProductDescription>
<ProductID>1</ProductID>
<ProductName>Road Bike</ProductName>
<GenID>0C866AE2-7AAA-474F-8794-7538986268AE</GenID>
<VocID>AF05E961-9BC3-4249-A4A7-C6146D6FC614</VocID>
<Features>
  <Warranty>1 year parts and labor</Warranty>
  <Maintenance>3 year parts and labor extended maintenance is available</Maintenance>
</Features>
</ProductDescription>
<ProductDescription>
<ProductID>2</ProductID>
<ProductName>Road Bike2</ProductName>
<GenID>D1DCAD29-08C6-401E-9A0A-2130DC5D8CD4</GenID>
<VocID>AF05E961-9BC3-4249-A4A7-C6146D6FC614</VocID>
<Features>
  <Warranty>2 year parts and labor</Warranty>
  <Maintenance>4 year parts and labor extended maintenance is available</Maintenance>
</Features>
</ProductDescription>
</Root>'
SET @ProdID =  @myDoc.value('(/Root/ProductDescription/ProductID)[2]', 'int' )
SELECT @ProdID
```

This will give me the ID for second item. If I change 
I have the `GenID` and `VocID`. Using that I need to query and get the other data.
Kindly help me to generate query for the same.I am using SQL Server 2012. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Someone vote to close.It will be helpful to understand, reason to choose close..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would select directly from the XML data and just move the item number you are selecting to the `nodes` rather than selecting an ID then filtering by that ID. That way you already have access to the other information.

E.g.

```
SELECT  ProductID = x.value('ProductID[1]', 'int'),
        ProductName = x.value('ProductName[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
        GenID = x.value('GenID[1]', 'uniqueidentifier')
FROM    @myDoc.nodes('/Root/ProductDescription[2]') prod (x);
```

---

**EDIT**

To get the records that match a given GenID and VocID you can use the [`exist()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) method:

```
DECLARE @VocID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'AF05E961-9BC3-4249-A4A7-C6146D6FC614',
        @GenID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'D1DCAD29-08C6-401E-9A0A-2130DC5D8CD4';

SELECT  ProductID = x.value('ProductID[1]', 'int'),
        ProductName = x.value('ProductName[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
        GenID = x.value('GenID[1]', 'uniqueidentifier')
FROM    @myDoc.nodes('/Root/ProductDescription') prod (x)
WHERE   x.exist('VocID[text() = sql:variable("@VocID")]') = 1
AND     x.exist('GenID[text() = sql:variable("@GenID")]') = 1;
```

Comment: there are n number of nodes and we have the GenID and VocID only.So I need to query the xml using GenID and VocID. Considering a normal select query we have select * from table where GenID={val} and VociD={val}

Comment: I am really not sure I understand your criteria, do you want the nth node, or do you want a node that matches a given `GenID`?

Comment: I want a node that matches the given GenID and VocID

Comment: Yes :) correct I modified it  and thought of posting it back. Thanks a lot :)